# DataSet Cascade and Memory consumption

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management, dataset

I have an application which uses DataSet.WriteXML to export data and DataSet.ReadXML to import data. During the import process I need to change certain primary keys as part of the application logic.

When there are over 500K records, it writes to XML and read from XML successfully. Once I change the primary key it waits some time and throws an OutOfMemory exception. The reason as I believe is, it has to do a lot of cascade updates. I tried BeginEdit and EndEdit during primary key change, but still failing in EndEdit in that case.

As I have understood, DataSets keeps some of previous data also in memory. Is there any way to optimize DataSet update operations in a way it consumes minimum memeory?

Comment: It would be more work, but have you considered writing all of the data into temporary database tables and doing the re-numbering at a temp db level?  500k is a lot of rows to hold in memory.  How many different tables are in your dataset?

Comment: @tgolisch: I've got around 70 different tables. Is it possible to create a temp db? I don't know about temporary database. Could you point me an example? Thanks.

Comment: I think you have some design problems with your application. I mean "500K records,..." )) Maybe you post some more information - code - to describe your problem?

Comment: @MikroDel: Obviously this way is not suitable for large records and there is a design problem. I am trying to find an enhancement to apply when updating any primary key in the DataSet; to reduce the memory consumption in cascade update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need more control then you'll need to remove some of the functionality that the dataset gives you.  One way of reducing memory caused by cascades is simple Don't Cascade. Update the tables ID's manually using the tables schema.

The idea is you can then control which rows are updated, AcceptChanges at any point, force GC mid update or anything else you might want to control.

I've created a simple test scenario which shows what I mean:

[image]

Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Planet">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Continent">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="PlanetID" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Country">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="ContinentID" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="County">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="CountryID" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="City">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="CountyID" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Street">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="CityID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="People">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="StreetID" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Job">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="PeopleID" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Pets">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="PeopleID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//Planet" />
      <xs:field xpath="ID" />
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="Continent_Constraint1" msdata:ConstraintName="Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//Continent" />
      <xs:field xpath="ID" />
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="Country_Constraint1" msdata:ConstraintName="Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//Country" />
      <xs:field xpath="ID" />
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="County_Constraint1" msdata:ConstraintName="Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//County" />
      <xs:field xpath="ID" />
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="City_Constraint1" msdata:ConstraintName="Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//City" />
      <xs:field xpath="ID" />
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="Street_Constraint1" msdata:ConstraintName="Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//Street" />
      <xs:field xpath="ID" />
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="People_Constraint1" msdata:ConstraintName="Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//People" />
      <xs:field xpath="ID" />
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="Job_Constraint1" msdata:ConstraintName="Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//Job" />
      <xs:field xpath="ID" />
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="Pets_Constraint1" msdata:ConstraintName="Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//Pets" />
      <xs:field xpath="ID" />
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:keyref name="Relation8" refer="People_Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//Pets" />
      <xs:field xpath="PeopleID" />
    </xs:keyref>
    <xs:keyref name="Relation7" refer="People_Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//Job" />
      <xs:field xpath="PeopleID" />
    </xs:keyref>
    <xs:keyref name="Relation6" refer="Street_Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//People" />
      <xs:field xpath="StreetID" />
    </xs:keyref>
    <xs:keyref name="Relation5" refer="City_Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//Street" />
      <xs:field xpath="CityID" />
    </xs:keyref>
    <xs:keyref name="Relation4" refer="County_Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//City" />
      <xs:field xpath="CountyID" />
    </xs:keyref>
    <xs:keyref name="Relation3" refer="Country_Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//County" />
      <xs:field xpath="CountryID" />
    </xs:keyref>
    <xs:keyref name="Relation2" refer="Continent_Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//Country" />
      <xs:field xpath="ContinentID" />
    </xs:keyref>
    <xs:keyref name="Relation1" refer="Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//Continent" />
      <xs:field xpath="PlanetID" />
    </xs:keyref>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And some code which generates a test case

```
    private void CreateRows(Int32 MaxBaseRows, Int32 MaxChildRows)
    {
        dataSet1.Clear();
        Int32 RowCount = 0;
        Random R = new Random();
        foreach (DataTable DT in dataSet1.Tables)
        {
            Int32 NewCount = R.Next(1, MaxBaseRows);
            foreach (var FK in DT.Constraints.OfType<ForeignKeyConstraint>())
            {
                NewCount = NewCount * R.Next(1, MaxChildRows);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < NewCount; i++)
            {
                DataRow DR = DT.NewRow();
                foreach (DataColumn DC in DT.Columns)
                {
                    if (DC.ColumnName == "ID")
                    {
                        DR[DC] = DT.Rows.Count;
                    }
                    else if (DC.DataType == typeof(Int32))
                    {
                        Boolean ValueSet = false;
                        foreach (var FK in DT.Constraints.OfType<ForeignKeyConstraint>())
                        {
                            if (FK.Columns.Contains(DC))
                            {
                                DR[DC] = R.Next(0, FK.RelatedTable.Rows.Count);
                                ValueSet = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!ValueSet)
                        {
                            DR[DC] = R.Next(0, 10000);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (DC.DataType == typeof(String))
                    {
                        DR[DC] = String.Format("{0}{1}", DT.TableName, DT.Rows.Count);
                    }
                }
                DT.Rows.Add(DR);
                RowCount++;
            }
        }
        label19.Text = RowCount.ToString();
        dataSet1.AcceptChanges();
    }


    private void UpdateUsingCascade()
    {
        EnableRelations();
        GC.Collect();
        long Mem = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
        if (dataSet1.Tables["Planet"].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dataSet1.Tables["Planet"].Rows[0]["ID"] = new Random().Next(BaseRowCount, BaseRowCount + 10);
        }
        Mem = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(false) - Mem;
        DataSet ds = dataSet1.GetChanges();
        Int32 Changes = ds.Tables.OfType<DataTable>().Sum(DT => DT.Rows.Count);
        label19.Text = Changes.ToString();
        label21.Text = Mem.ToString();
        dataSet1.AcceptChanges();
    }

    private void UpdateManually()
    {
        DisableRelations();
        GC.Collect();
        long Mem = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(false);

        DataTable DT = dataSet1.Tables["Planet"];
        Int32 ChangeCount = 0;
        if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataColumn DC = DT.Columns["ID"];
            Int32 oldValue = Convert.ToInt32(DT.Rows[0][DC]);
            DT.Rows[0][DC] = new Random().Next(BaseRowCount + 20,BaseRowCount + 30);
            Int32 newValue = Convert.ToInt32(DT.Rows[0][DC]);
            foreach (DataRelation Relation in DT.ChildRelations)
            {
                if (Relation.ParentColumns.Contains(DC))
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn CC in Relation.ChildColumns)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow DR in Relation.ChildTable.Rows)
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToInt32(DR[CC]) == oldValue)
                            {
                                DR[CC] = newValue;
                                ChangeCount++;
                                dataSet1.AcceptChanges();
                                GC.Collect();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Mem = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(false) - Mem;
        label20.Text = ChangeCount.ToString();
        label22.Text = Mem.ToString();
        dataSet1.AcceptChanges();
    }

    private void EnableRelations()
    {
        dataSet1.EnforceConstraints = true;
        foreach (DataRelation Relation in dataSet1.Relations)
        {
            Relation.ChildKeyConstraint.UpdateRule = Rule.Cascade;
        }
    }

    private void DisableRelations()
    {
        dataSet1.EnforceConstraints = false;
        foreach (DataRelation Relation in dataSet1.Relations)
        {
            Relation.ChildKeyConstraint.UpdateRule = Rule.None;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Excellent, actually I have already solved the problem by setting EnforceConstraints false. And update other records manually. Quite similar to what you proposed. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

SHCJ - you should use `BufferedStream`:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(pathToYourFile);
BufferedStream bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(fileStream);
dataSet.ReadXml(bufferedStream);
```

*Update*

Try this one for your write operations please:

```
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(_pathToYourFile))
{
   /* write oprations */
}
```

Comment: BufferedStream consumes huge memory chunk and it throws outofMemory exception in the middle of ReadXml.

Comment: This happens when I update it after I ReadXML. Of course I am already using 'using' for both write and read.

Comment: @SHCJ - I think you have some design problems with your application. I mean "500K records,..." )) Maybe you post some more information - code - to describe your problem?

Comment: Obviously this way is not suitable for large records and there is a design problem. I am trying to find an enhancement to apply when updating any primary key in the DataSet; to reduce the memory consumption in cascade update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try
{

    //Logic to load your file

    var xelmOriginal = new XElement("Root");

    for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
    {
        var item = new XElement("Item");
        item.SetAttributeValue("id", i);
        xelmOriginal.Add(item);
    }

    // Logic to transform each element

    var xelmRootTransformed = new XElement("Root");

    foreach (var element in xelmOriginal.Elements())
    {
        var transformedItem =
            new XElement("Transformed",
                            element.
                                Attributes()
                                .Single(x => x.Name.LocalName.Equals("id")));


        xelmRootTransformed.Add(transformedItem);
    }

    //Logic to save your transformed file
}catch(Exception e)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Failed");
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine("Success");
```

The key point here is you are separating your input and output. I.e. you don't transform a file and immediately write to it; You'll screw up your enumeration.

Instead, read your file one element at a time, and write to a temporary output one element at a time; in theory, you'll only ever have one alive element active.

Comment: I am not sure whether you really understand my issue. I have no problems in WriteXml and ReadXml. Basically my issue is I get outofMemory exception during cascade update process in DataSet. What I am after is a way to reduce the memory consumption when I update a primary key (I have to change the primary key, which is inevitable according to the business logic).

Answer (score 0):

DataSets are intelligent beasts. They can not only read/write/hold/filter the data, but they also do CHANGE TRACKING, so later updates/writes/deletes are faster (when working with database, not just XML files).

It might have happened, that your DataSet has change tracking turned on, which would force it to always remember not only what is the current data, but also how the data looked like before, and how is the new data related to old ones. If you just keep the DataSet as a "container" for current workload, you don't needed the caching/changetracking - just turn it off. I mean, if it is possible - I don't remember currently if nor how it can be done. However, I'm quite sure that you can flush the changes by calling .AcceptChanges() or by diposing old DS and creating new DS for each new batch of data to be loaded. The latter of course will NOT help for OOMs thrown during sequential updates on current batch. AcceptChanges cannot help if OOM is thrown at the point of the very first PK update. You can 'accept' changes only after one full operation ends, and even so, there will be no 'meantime' when you could issue it. But, if OOM is thrown after a few changes PKs, then calling AcceptChanges after each one, or after every few ones - may help.

Please note that I'm guessing. Your DS is not connected to DB, so the change tracking *might* be off by default. But I doubt that, I remember that even for XML file you can ask the DS to dump the data accompanied with a change log.. I think it is on by default.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I am actually aware of this. My issue is I get OutOfMemory Exception when I update a primary key which causes some cascade updates. What I am looking for is a way to reduce the memory consumption during cascade update process.